# Microservice : Database design to keep request states

Tags: microservices

I am trying to implement microservice architecture in my backend application, One of my services receiving some data from another service, and this data are stored in MySQL DB, A cronjob read this data from DB and sending multiple requests to another services to complete some jobs like account create, billing info create and etc, all of this requests applying to exist record in DB, my problem is handling failures, This requests can be failed for any reason, How can I design DB for handling failures and retries?

Should I create multiple columns to handling states?
Like ACCOUNT_REQUESTED, ACCOUNT_CREATED_FAILED, account_create_failed_count and something like this

Comment: Your services must be following some work flow e.g. create account then accept bills etc. You shall keep one transaction ID that shall propagate to all services to keep track of your requests and attached to single user for example. Then save each state in DB if not using any log system e.g. Apache Kafka etc

Comment: Further more that is your internal Business logic how you need to go for retries.In one of our case we had following States i.e. Config Failure, Process Failure, General Failure. For Config failure it must retry request once configurations are set.For Process Failure it is up to business logic either to process again or not depending upon some rules. and general failures may be any runtime OR Unknown exceptions. which may need human intervention i.e. Admin to sort out requests for reprocessing. that is just in short i can say.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single column ( not multiple columns ) which maintains state because any Entity can have ONLY one state at a time..
And as usman mentioned; you can have retry logic etc. depending on your business logic. .. If workflow is really complex; there are some open source solutions for that also; but I don't think your case is that complicated... And as usman mentioned; you can use some messaging solutions like Kafka to make things asynchronus.